# Rewrite trailing ampersand in nginx, without a 301

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am looking for a solution for nginx remove trailing "&" from URL, without returning a 301.

Example:

- Url: https://example.com?&
- Nginx should rewrite to: https://example.com

Is it possible?

I tried without success with

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\?&$) {
  set $pagepath $1;
  rewrite ^ /$1 break;
}
```

Comment: The `&` is the query string - the URI without the query string is already available as `$uri` - you do not need to rewrite it.

Comment: As @RichardSmith already mentioned, rewriting URI would not affect your query string, you should change the `$args` variable instead. Do you need to keep other query variables, i.e. process `https://example.com&a=b&` request as `https://example.com?a=b`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes, I want to keep any other query parameters.
Short story, URLs ending with "&" are messing up a couple of things, I would like to rewrite them at the nginx level if possible, but without returning a 301.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
map $args $stripped_args {
    ~(.*)&$  $1;
    default  $args;
}

server {
    ...
    set $args $stripped_args;
    ...
}
```